# too many values to unpack python with nested list

Tags: python, nested-lists, items

```
list_a = [['name1', 4.12]]
list_b = [['name2', 2, 'name4', 4, 'name4', 1, 'name4', 6, 'name2', 6]]

def data_sums(matrix):
  sums = defaultdict(int)

  for name, value in matrix:
    sums[name] += value 

  result = [[k,v] for k,v in sums.items()]
  return result
```

When I pass `list_a` to `data_sums`, it returns `[['name1', 4.12]]` (for this specific case it has nothing to sum).

When I pass `list_b` to `data_sums`, it returns an error:

> for name, value in matrix: ValueError: too many values to unpack

I've tried to understand why this is happening but both lists seem identical in their structure of nesting.

Comment: each sublist in `list_a` has two elements, which you are assigning to `name` and `value`.  Each sublist of `list_b` has ten elements, which you are trying to assign to two identifiers.

Comment: They are *not* identical at all. One is a list with another list that contains two elements (which is why it succeeds in unpacking into two variables) the other is a list which contains another list with 10 elements, which is why it fails to unpack into two variables.

Comment: @Patrick Haugh
Correct. Thanks for pointing it out. I've previously had a .extend instead of .append in some other place in the script, so now that I've changed it to .append I have `list_b = [ [ ['name2', 2], ['name4', 4], ['name4', 1], ['name4', 6], ['name2', 6] ] ]`
It looks like a triple-nested list, while list_a is only double-nested.

Can this be the issue, since the error remains... ?

Comment: Yes. Now the sublist of `list_b` has five elements (the five length-2 lists). You need to make it so that every sublist of `list_b` has two elements.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you're getting a `ValueError` when passing in `list_b`, is because when doing:

```
for name, value in matrix:
    ...
```

Python expects the elements in `some_list` to be able to be unpacked into two variables; `name` and `value`. This is true for `list_a`. `list_a` has one element that can be be unpacked into the two variables `name` and `value`. However, `list_b` has one element that has more than two elements. This means it cannot be unpacked into just two variables. Thus, the exception is raised.

The obvious solution is to restructure `list_b` into a list consisting of elements that each have two elements. A general way to do this is to use the `grouper` recipe from the itertools library:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> 
>>> def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
        args = [iter(iterable)] * n
        return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

>>> list_b = [['name2', 2, 'name4', 4, 'name4', 1, 'name4', 6, 'name2', 6]]
>>> list_b = list(grouper(list_b[0], 2))
>>> list_b
[('name2', 2), ('name4', 4), ('name4', 1), ('name4', 6), ('name2', 6)]
>>>
```

Another method of solving this problem that's less readable and less general, is to use list slicing:

```
>>> list_b = [['name2', 2, 'name4', 4, 'name4', 1, 'name4', 6, 'name2', 6]]
>>> inner = list_b[0]
>>> list_b = [(a, b) for (a, b) in zip(inner[::2], inner[1::2])]
>>> list_b
[('name2', 2), ('name4', 4), ('name4', 1), ('name4', 6), ('name2', 6)]
>>>
```

Comment: Please check my comment on the post, I've modified it to be correct but the error persists.

Comment: @YafimSimanovsky You still have only _one_ top-level element in `list_b`. Your real data is nested three levels deep. You need to flatten `list_b` into a  list consisting of elements that each have two elements.

Comment: great use of `zip_longest`! +1

Comment: @Ajax1234 Thanks! I appreciate it. One step closer to that gold Python badge ;-)

Answer (score 2):

### The problem

You need to change `list_b`to:

```
list_b = [['name2', 2], ['name4', 4], ['name4', 1], ['name4', 6], ['name2', 6]]
```

Now:

```
>>> data_sums(list_b)
[['name2', 8], ['name4', 11]]
```

because in this loop:

```
for name, value in matrix:
```

conceptionally this happens:

```
name, value = ['name2', 2]
name, value = ['name4', 4]
...
```

This is called unpacking.

For your `list_b` this happens:

```
name, value = 'name2'
```

which throws this error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

because there is only one value at the right hand side but Python needs two.

### Alternative Solution

You can start with flat list and just zip each second element together by starting a zero and one:

```
flat_list = ['name2', 2, 'name4', 4, 'name4', 1, 'name4', 6, 'name2', 6]
sums = defaultdict(int)
for name, value in zip(flat_list[::2], flat_list[1::2]):
    sums[name] += value
result = [[k,v] for k,v in sums.items()]
```

and result is:

```
[['name2', 8], ['name4', 11]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`list_b` should be a list of 2 item lists:

`list_b = [['name2', 2], ['name4', 4], ['name4', 1], ['name4', 6], ['name2', 6]]`

Answer (score 1):

It's not doing what you think it's doing.  In the first list it's splitting the two values apart into `name`, and `value`.  This works because you have exactly the amount of items in your list as you do in your for loop.

For the second list, there are 10 items, which is way more than the two you are unpacking in the for loop.

In order for this to work your values would need to be nested in pairs of two.

This would solve your problem:

```
list_b = [['name2', 2], ['name4', 4], [ 'name4', 1], ['name4', 6], ['name2', 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`list_b` only contains one element, `['name2', 2, 'name4', 4, 'name4', 1, 'name4', 6, 'name2', 6]`. To unpack `list_b` in a `for` loop, you would need to use ten variables:

```
for name1, val, name2, val2, name3, val3, name4, val4, name5, val5 in list_b:
   pass
```

Since the above is long and unpythonic, you can flatten `list_b` and then regroup:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def data_sums(matrix):
   sums = defaultdict(int)
   for name, value in matrix:
      sums[name] += value 
   result = [[k,v] for k,v in sums.items()]
   return result

list_b = [['name2', 2, 'name4', 4, 'name4', 1, 'name4', 6, 'name2', 6]]
list_b = [i for b in list_b for i in b]
final_b = [list_b[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(list_b), 2)]
print(data_sums(final_b))
```

Output:

```
[['name4', 11], ['name2', 8]]
```